# Detect when command line tool will exit

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm creating a command line utility in Swift. In the `main.swift` I have a class, that opens up a process with `Process`. Until this process is running, my application should run as well. I accomplish this by calling:

```
let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

let myClass = MainClass(..., errorHandler: {
    print("anything went wrong here, so end the application")
    sema.signal()   // ends this programm
})

sema.wait()
```

This works pretty well... when the errorHandler is called, `sema.signal()` ends my tool. But how can I have the opposite way? When I end my app manually (in Xcode), the process continues running.

I have this code to open up the process:

```
self.task = Process()
self.task!.executableURL = runURL
self.task!.currentDirectoryURL = directoryURL
self.task!.arguments = arguments
// The ouput of the process
let errorPipe = Pipe()
let outputPipe = Pipe()
self.task!.standardError = errorPipe
self.task!.standardOutput = outputPipe
self.errorHandler = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading
self.outputHandler = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading

self.errorHandler!.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
  ...
  errorHandler()
}

self.outputHandler!.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
  ...
}

try? self.task!.run()
```

**EDIT**

I'm calling `/bin/sh tail -f myfile.log` in the process to observe a logfile. After ending, tail is still running in the activity monitor.

Comment: I exactly have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ending the process in Xcode sends a `SIGKILL` and as far as I understand, you cannot do anything to react on that, because the OS kills the process. But what you can do is react on the `SIGINT`, if you press `Ctrl + C` in the terminal:

```
signal(SIGINT) { signal in
    task.terminate()
    sema.signal()
}

sema.wait()
```